# One liner for adding an element to an array that may not exist

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to condensate to condensate into one line the lines that check if the array exist and creates and empty one, and the one that pushes a new element into it?

```
hash = {}
(('a'..'z').to_a+('a'..'z').to_a).shuffle.each do |e|
    hash[:"#{e}"] ||= []
    hash[:"#{e}"] << rand(10)
end
```

I am looking something more of the style "||=" but for the "<<" operand
thanks for the help

Comment: I cannot parse your question.

Comment: i checked the code and it's valid. don't know what might be wrong. i'm using ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(hash[e.to_sym] ||= []) << rand(10)
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. also thanks for the tip on converting the string to symbol

Answer (score 1):

You could define the hash differently instead:

```
hash = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = []}
(('a'..'z').to_a+('a'..'z').to_a).shuffle.each do |e|
    hash[:"#{e}"] << rand(10)
end
```

Comment: @pguardiario could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: For example you might mistakenly expect hash['foo'] to be nil.

Answer (score -1):

`arr.inject({}){|h, x| (h[x.to_sym] || = []) << rand(10); h }`